# Bootstrap methods didn't work inside requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs

I have a view like this

```
'use strict';
define([
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
      'bootstrap'
       ],

function($, _, Backbone, Bootstrap){
    var IssueRowView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',

        template: _.template(row_template),

        events: {
            'click a': 'showDetails',
        },

        detailView:'',

        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        showData: function(){
            $('.nav-tabs a[href="#data_issues"]').tab('show');
        },

        showDetails: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.model.get('auto_issue')){
                this.showData();
            }
            else {
                this.detailView = new detail_view({model: this.model, el: this.parent.el});
                this.detailView.render();
            }
        },

    });
    return IssueRowView;
});
```

I need to make Bootstrap tab active after click on link, but it didn't work. Event triggers but nothing happens. And the most strange that if I move

```
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#data_issues"]').tab('show');
```

for example to initialise method it works fine.

Do you have any suggestions how to make it works?

UPD:  I've created listeners for 'show.bs.tab' and 'shown.bs.tab' events of "#data_issues" tab and 'show.bs.tab' has been fired after showData() method, but 'shown.bs.tab' has not.

Comment: When you say nothing happens, you mean that : this.showData() is called but the .tab('show') inside it does nothing?

Comment: Exactly, active tab didn't change.

Comment: just for the sake of curiosity, could you check what $('.nav-tabs a[href="#data_issues"]') returns inside showData() ?

Comment: I also thought about it, but jquery seems to work fine. It returns "Object[a#data-link #data_issues]"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find any reasonable answer, so I change tabs and tab-conten divs by myself, without any bootstrap methods.